# Script for running grouping and limit query against multiple database

Tags: php, sql, grouping, limit

If I want show data from one database in sql server 2000, then I write php script like this:

```
<?php
// connect to db branch
include "connect_dbbranch.php"
//example query
$kueri = "SELECT TOP 20 COUNT(ID) AS ID, SUM(NILAI) AS NILAI FROM table WHERE tgl =   
'09/01/2013' " ORDER BY NILAI DESC
$do=mssql_query($kueri);
//looping
while($result=mssql_fetch_array($do)){
 echo "$result[ID]<br>";
 echo "$result[NILAI]<br>"; 
}
?>
```

If the script above runs, it will show 20 data order by DESC NILAI.
And now I want to display 20 data order by DESC NILAI just like script above did, but from all database branch.

This is my logic and script (it doesn't display 20 data but 113) :

```
<?php
// connect ip server
include "../../../config/dball.php";
// select database name
$branch = mssql_query("SELECT NM_DATA, NM_BRANCH FROM Branch ORDER BY KD_BRANCH ASC");
while ($allbranch = mssql_fetch_array($branch)){
  //connect for each database
  include "../../../config/db.php";
  mssql_select_db($allbranch[NM_DATA]);

  //example query for selecting data
  $kueri = "SELECT TOP 20 COUNT(ID) AS ID, SUM(NILAI) AS NILAI
  FROM table WHERE tgl = '09/01/2013' " ORDER BY NILAI DESC
  $do=mssql_query($kueri);
  //looping
  while($result=mssql_fetch_array($do)){
   echo "$result[ID]<br>";
   echo "$result[NILAI]<br>";
  }
} // END LOOPING ALL BRANCH
?>
```

How to fix this, so I can get 20 data from all database branch ?